# Play YouTube in 2x automatically in Firefox

Tags: youtube

How can I make videos play automatically in 2x speed in Firefox? In other words, I want 2x to be the default speed when opening a video.

Comment: If you just set it to 2x speed and stay in one tab it should be the default for all of the videos in that one tab. At least that works for me.